# pandas merge based on condition

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two large dataframes, both have datetime column. One of them the datetime format is `%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S` and another one is in millisecond format: `%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f`. How can I join these two dataframes **efficiently**  based on a part of datetime column (join based on seconds)?

I know that we can use pandas merge function or use something like:

`df1.merge(df2, left_on=['df1_column'], right_on=['df2_column'])`

But is there a way to customize this merge, so that we can join two dataframe based on one column from left side and part of another column from right side (without adding any additional column to the dataframes)?

```
    import pandas as pd

    df1 = pd.DataFrame({'datetime_s': ['2018-09-09T12:25:26', '2018-09-09T12:25:27','2018-09-09T12:25:28']\
                    ,'value': [1, 2, 3]})
    df2 = pd.DataFrame({'datetime_m': ['2018-09-09T12:25:26.780', '2018-09-09T12:25:26.650', '2018-09-09T12:25:27.320']\
                    ,'value': [5, 6, 7]})
    # add something to the following line to merge them based on the second
    df1.merge(df2, left_on=['datetime_s'], right_on=['datetime_m'])
```

the output should be:

```
datetime_s             datetime_m                 df1.value   df2.value
2018-09-09T12:25:26    2018-09-09T12:25:26.780      1           5
2018-09-09T12:25:26    2018-09-09T12:25:26.650      1           6
2018-09-09T12:25:27    2018-09-09T12:25:27.320      2           7
```

Comment: would you paste a testable dataframes fragements?

Comment: One possible way would be to break your dataframe and make a temp dataframe by filling only the parts which you want to add at the end of right side. then merge both of them. Can you please post a small example?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Added testable dataframes

Comment: @DeepBhatt Like I said, I do not want to break down the dataframe, the dataframe is very large. Posted an example.

Answer (score 0):

How about :

```py
df1.merge(df2, left_on=df1.df1_column.apply(lambda x :x.second), 
              right_on=df2.df2_column.apply(lambda x : x.second))
```

Comment: It might work for small dataframes, but for large dataframes (even with ~ 1 million records each), Python gives memory error.