# Efficient way to merge two large dataframes based on a condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, pandas-groupby

I have two dataframes like as shown below. Already referred the posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23508351/how-to-do-workaround-a-conditional-join-in-python-pandas), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65032124/compare-two-dates-in-pandas-dataframe-with-current-date-and-create-new-column), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57077563/pandas-merge-based-on-condition) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45869886/python-pandas-how-to-merge-based-on-an-or-condition). Don't mark it as duplicate

```
id,id2,app_date
1,'A',20/3/2017
1,'A',28/8/2017
3,'B',18/10/2017
4,'C',15/2/2017

tf = pd.read_clipboard(sep=',')
tf['app_date'] = pd.to_datetime(tf['app_date'],dayfirst=True)

id,valid_from,valid_to,s_flag
1,20/1/2017,30/4/2017,0
1,28/11/2017,15/2/2018,1
1,18/12/2017,24/2/2018,0
2,15/7/2017,15/11/2017,1
2,2/2/2017,2/6/2017,0
2,11/5/2016,11/6/2016,1

df = pd.read_clipboard(sep=',')
df['valid_from'] = pd.to_datetime(df['valid_from'],dayfirst=True)
df['valid_to'] = pd.to_datetime(df['valid_to'],dayfirst=True)
```

I would like to do the below

a) check whether `tf['app_date']` is within the `df['valid_from']` and `df['valid_to']` for matching id

b) If yes, then copy the column `s_flag` to `tf` dataframe for matching `id`

I tried the below but am not sure whether the below is efficient for million records plus dataframes

```
t1 = tf.merge(df, how = 'left',on=['id'])
t1 = t1.loc[(t1.app_date >= t1.valid_from) & (t1.app_date <= t1.valid_to),['id','s_flag','app_date']]
tf.merge(t1, how = 'inner',on=['id','app_date'])
```

While the above works in sample data, but in real data, for some records, I encounter issues like below

[image].

You can see that `9/1/2017` approval date doesn't meet the condition for the 2nd and 3rd row but it is still returned as output. This is incorrect.

I expect my output to be like as shown below

```
    id  app_date    s_flag
0   1   2017-03-20  0.0
2   3   2017-10-18  NaN
3   4   2017-02-15  NaN
```

Comment: "not sure whether it is fool proof and will work for scenarios (huge datasets)" - test it and find out.  It's not that hard to generate fake data with millions of rows.  I don't see anything wrong with the code you've got.

Comment: btw, I already tried in real dataframe worth million plus records and it's just loading but no output yet.

Comment: The post is updated with screenshot

Comment: The issue is the input dataframe has repeating `ids` but different `id2s`.